Beam splitter split ratios from a reflected beam
Good day all, I am not a physicist or familiar with optics, I have a question that maybe basic.
If I had a non polarized beam splitter with a 90:10 (R:T) split ratio, assuming everything is 'ideal', had a light source entering the beam splitter then being reflected back off a mirror towards a detector like in the image below:

What percentage of the light would be at the detector, would it be 10% as that's what the the transmissive percentage of the beam splitter coating is or 90%?
Thank you!

In this scenario (assuming a "perfect" beam splitter and mirror), the incoming light would be split 90/10, then the 90% reflection R would be reflected completely by the mirror, i.e., remain 90%. This would then further be split again at the beam splitter interface in the same 90/10 ratio, leading to 90% * 0.9 = 81% being reflected back towards your source and 90% * 0.1 = 9% hitting the detector.
That is all under the assumption of perfect optics. Things get complicated once you introduce polarisation, different angles or wavelength-dependent performance of components.

Thank you appreciate it.
